# OracleCommand command, ExecuteNonQuery issue

Tags: c#, sql, oracle10g, executenonquery, oraclecommand

I have to clear certain tables in the oracle database however when I'm having issues with running the following code

```
public static void ClearDataTables(IList<string> tableNames)
        {
            string connectionString = "CONNECTIONSTRING";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();
                foreach (string table in tableNames)
                {
                    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    string sql = String.Format("DELETE FROM TOA_REPORTING.{0}", table);
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

I am calling this method with this list

```
ClearDataTables(new List<string> { "GROUP_DEFINITION", "GROUP_REPORT_EMAIL_LIST", "GROUP_EQUIPMENT_GROUP_STN_XREF"});
```

It runs the first two tables fine, however on the third one, it gets stuck and the application runs forever...

Funny thing is, when I switch "GROUP_REPORT_EMAIL_LIST" and "GROUP_EQUIPMENT_GROUP_STN_XREF"
The application runs forever after the it hits the second table name.

So in conclusion, the function runs forever when it hits "GROUP_EQUIPMENT_GROUP_STN_XREF". I've verified that the SQL generated works by testing it out on toad.

Anyone else ran into this issue?

EDIT - The first two tables does indeed get cleared when it runs.

Solution

```
string connectionString = "CONNECTIONSTRING";
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                OracleTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
                command.Transaction = trans;
                foreach (string table in tableNames)
                {
                    string sql = String.Format("DELETE FROM TOA_REPORTING.{0}", table);
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                trans.Commit();
            }
```

TRUNCATE would have been a very nice solution, however I do not have the privileges to do so!

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you forgotten to commit your changes in Toad (or any other client)? An open transaction will cause it to wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a lot of data in that table? This would explain, why it takes so long to delete the data.
Anyway, I suggest to use `TRUNC` for clearing tables.

Comment: You can't be sure the OP actually needs undo capability that isn't available when `trunc` is used to clear the table.

Comment: @Mike: How is it possible to undo a `delete` after a `commit`?

Comment: It's possible to go through recovery scenarios through the UNDO functionality. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14196/storage003.htm

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I think I fail to understand how this relates to undoing committed deletes.

Comment: In a production environment, it is highly likely that the data being deleted needs to be available for manual recovery (flasback in the doc) up to a certain point. Truncating the tables eliminates this possibility. You didn't provide any reason why you suggested TRUNCATE over DELETE.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the explanation. I don't share your POV that it is "highly likely" that flashback is activated in a production environment. Several big companies I have worked for, haven't had it activated. The reason for my suggestion: Basically, because it is faster.

Comment: I guess they weren't in highly regulated industries? Anyway, this whole thread is now off topic...

Answer (score 3):

Large number of deletes can be very slow, especially if you run them in one transaction.  If you don't need the transaction at all, use:

```
truncate table YourTable
```

If you do, split the `delete` over small-sized transactions.  Basically run:

```
delete from YourTable where rownum < 100
```

until the table is empty.  See for example this [blog post](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/PL_SQL/PLSQL_3.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write a stored procedure that does all of the deletions or truncations and invoke the SP once, rather than have a loop client-side.

EDIT: It would also be better not to create the command object inside the loop. Create it once outside the loop with a table-name parameter, and then invoke it feeding it a different parameter value with each iteration. But the SP is to be preferred.